# Set theory question with real, rational and irrational.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'd really appreciate your help with this one:

I got the following:

R = being real numbers

Q = rational numbers

N = natural numbers

$ R^2 $ being the  pair of $ (a,b)$  with $a,b$ being real numbers

$$
〖[(R - Q )∩ R^2 ] 〗^c ∪ N
$$

My reasoning tell me R - Q would give me all the irrational numbers, the intersection between the irrational numbers and $R^2$  would be empty.

After that this is where it gets fuzzy.

Could someone clarify what would the answer be?

Comment: The universe set $U$ since the complement of an empty set is the universe. Since $\mathbb N \subset U$, $U \cup \mathbb N = U$.

Comment: Are you sure your version of question is right? [Seems peculiar to set up a problem where a one dimensional set gets intersected with a two dimensional one, inside the inner brackets]

Comment: Yes I found it weird too. I also find weird the fact that they don't define the universe at all.

Comment: It's possible that they are considering $\mathbb R = \mathbb R\times \{0\} = \{(x,0)|x \in \mathbb R\}$ and that the universe is $\mathbb R^2$ of which $\mathbb R, \mathbb Q,\mathbb N$ are subsets.  In that case the answer is $\{(x,y)|$ if $y=0$ then $x$ is rational but if $y\ne 0$ then $x$ can be anything$\}$

Answer (score 1):

When you take a complement, you have to specify what universe you are taking the complement with respect to.  You are correct that the intersection of $\Bbb {R-Q}$, which consists of single numbers (they happen to be irrational, but that doesn't matter) and $\Bbb R^2$, which consists of ordered pairs is the empty set.  The complement is whatever universe you are working in.  Assuming your universe is a superset of $\Bbb N$, the final answer is the universe.

Comment: I agree with you both. Thank you very much for your valuable insight.

Answer (score 1):

$R - Q$ is the irrationals.  This is a subset of the reals.

$R^2$ is the set of ordered pairs.  These are not real numbers; they are *pairs* of numbers..

$(R-Q) \cap R^2$ is the intersection of the irrational real numbers and the ordered pairs, or in other words all the irrational numbers that are also an ordered pair of reals.

Well, *no* number is also a pair of numbers.  Those are *entirely* different types of things.

So $(R-Q)\cap R^2$ is the empty set.

The complement of the empty set is everything that isn't in the empty set.  Nothing is in the empty set so *everything* is in the complement of the empty set.  $[(R-Q)]\cap R^2]^c$ is the entire universe of things.  (We haven't actually been told what our actual universe is.... )

And UNIVERSE $\cup  N$ is everything that is either something in the universe or a natural number.  Well, everything is something in the universe so this set is everything in the universe.

So $[(R-Q)\cap R^2]^c \cup N = $UNIVERSE.

======

Alternative answer.  $\mathbb R\times \{0\} = \{(x,0)|x\in \mathbb R\} \cong \mathbb R$ and so *maybe* the question is taking $\mathbb R$ to be *equal* to $\mathbb R\times \{0\}$.

If so the universe is $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb N\cong \mathbb N\times\{0\} = \{(n,0)|n\in \mathbb N\}$ etc are all subsets of $\mathbb R^2$.

In which case:

$(\mathbb R-\mathbb Q)\cap \mathbb R^2 = \{(x,0)|x\not \in \mathbb Q\}$.

And $[(\mathbb R-\mathbb Q)\cap \mathbb R^2]^c = \{(x,y)|y \in \mathbb R, x\in \mathbb R$ and if $y=0$ then $x\in \mathbb Q\}$.

And $[(\mathbb R-\mathbb Q)\cap \mathbb R^2]^c\cup \mathbb N = \{(x,y)|y \in \mathbb R, x\in \mathbb R$ and if $y=0$ then $x\in \mathbb Q$ or $x\in \mathbb N\}$.

But as $\mathbb N\subset \mathbb Q$ that is $[(\mathbb R-\mathbb Q)\cap \mathbb R^2]^c\cup \mathbb N = \{(x,y)|y \in \mathbb R, x\in \mathbb R$ and if $y=0$ then $x\in \mathbb Q\}$

Comment: Great answer! The tutor could had done that  asumption of R x (0). Thank you very much!

Comment: IMO that *isn't* a valid assumption unless it is pointed out.  And then you have to state whether the universe is $\mathbb R^{|\mathbb N|}$ or $\mathbb R^2$. ... The third possibility is the are defining ordered pairs as a form of set so $\mathbb R^2 \subset P(\mathbb R)$ but I don't think that is common (if it is ever done) and *somehow* in some ZFC many defining $\mathbb R$ as sets of sets so that $\mathbb R\subset P(\mathbb R)$ (but somehow without the contradiction) but... that seems like a *real* abuse.  I'm inclined to think the question is just plain wrong.

Comment: The more I think about it i, the more I incline towards thinking the same thing. Thank you for help